# How to correctly use Hooks in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React, and I have to build a timeout mechanism for a page. I used *react-idle-timer*, with some help found on the Internet. However, when I try to access the page, I get a Minified React error #321, in which it tells me that I used hooks incorrectly.

Can you please take a look on the following code and point me in the right direction? Thanks

```
import React from "react"
import NavBar from "./Navbar"
import "../styles/Upload.css"
import LinearProgressWithLabel from "./LinearProgressWithLabel"
import axios from "axios"
import Logout from "./Logout"
import { useIdleTimer } from 'react-idle-timer'
import { format } from 'date-fns'

export default function Upload() {
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = React.useState();
    const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(0);

    const timeout = 3000;
    const [remaining, setRemaining] = React.useState(timeout);
    const [elapsed, setElapsed] = React.useState(0);
    const [lastActive, setLastActive] = React.useState(+new Date());
    const [isIdle, setIsIdle] = React.useState(false);

    const handleOnActive = () => setIsIdle(false);
    const handleOnIdle = () => setIsIdle(true);

    const {
        reset,
        pause,
        resume,
        getRemainingTime,
        getLastActiveTime,
        getElapsedTime
    } = useIdleTimer({
        timeout,
        onActive: handleOnActive,
        onIdle: handleOnIdle
    });

    const handleReset = () => reset();
    const handlePause = () => pause();
    const handleResume = () => resume();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setRemaining(getRemainingTime())
        setLastActive(getLastActiveTime())
        setElapsed(getElapsedTime())

        setInterval(() => {
            setRemaining(getRemainingTime())
            setLastActive(getLastActiveTime())
            setElapsed(getElapsedTime())
        }, 1000)
    }, []);

    function changeHandler(event) {
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0])
    };

    function handleSubmission() {
        if (selectedFile) {
            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);
            reader.onload = () => {
                sendFileData(selectedFile.name, new Uint8Array(reader.result), 4096)
            };
        }
    };

    function sendFileData(name, data, chunkSize) {
        function sendChunk(offset) {
            var chunk = data.subarray(offset, offset + chunkSize) || ''
            var opts = { method: 'POST', body: chunk }
            var url = '/api/uploaddb?offset=' + offset + '&name=' + encodeURIComponent(name)

            setProgress(offset / data.length * 100)

            fetch(url, opts).then(() => {
                if (chunk.length > 0) {
                    sendChunk(offset + chunk.length)
                }
                else {
                    axios.post('/api/uploaddb/done', { name })
                        .then(setProgress(100))
                        .catch(e => console.log(e));
                }
            })
        }
        sendChunk(0);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Timeout: {timeout}ms</h1>
                    <h1>Time Remaining: {remaining}</h1>
                    <h1>Time Elapsed: {elapsed}</h1>
                    <h1>Last Active: {format(lastActive, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:ss.SSS')}</h1>
                    <h1>Idle: {isIdle.toString()}</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={handleReset}>RESET</button>
                    <button onClick={handlePause}>PAUSE</button>
                    <button onClick={handleResume}>RESUME</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Upload</h1>
            <input type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
            {!selectedFile ? <p className="upload--progressBar">Select a file</p> : <LinearProgressWithLabel className="upload--progressBar" variant="determinate" value={progress} />}
            <br />
            <div>
                <button disabled={!selectedFile} onClick={handleSubmission}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you please add your error stack trace for better understanding the issue, which hook making error

Comment: To make it easier for people to help you should remove fluff in the code block that is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: I've created a playground here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-mkxko5 - which after removing your additional components and axios seems to work fine.

What version of React are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case, you should avoid setting states inside the useEffect function, because this causes an infinite loop. Everytime you set a state value, your component is meant to render again, so if you put states setters inside a useEffect function it will cause an infinite loop, because useEffect function executes once before rendering component.

As an alternative you can set your states values outside your useEffect and then put your states inside the useEffect array param. The states inside this array will be "listened" by useEffect, when these states change, useEffect triggers.

Something like this:

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
    
}, [state1, state2, state3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**state anti-pattern**

You are using a state anti-pattern. Read about [Single Source Of Truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned) in the React Docs.

- [react-idle-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-idle-timer) provides `getRemainingTime`, `getLastActiveTime` and `getElapsedTime`
- They should not be copied to the state of your component
- They are not functions

  - `getRemainingTime()`, `getLastActiveTime()`, or `getElapsedTime()` are incorrect

To fix each:

- `getRemainingTime` should not be stored in state of its own

  - Remove `const [remaining, setRemaining] = useState(timeout)`
  - Remove `setRemaining(getRemainingTime)` both places in `useEffect`
  - Change `<h1>Time Remaining: {remaining}</h1>`

    - To `<h1>Time Remaining: {getRemainingTime}</h1>`

The same is true for `lastActive`.

- `getLastActive` should be be stored in state of its own

  - Remove `const [lastActive, setLastActive] = React.useState(+new Date())`
  - Remove `setLastActive(getLastActiveTime())` both places in `useEffect`
  - Change `<h1>Last Active: {format(lastActive, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:ss.SSS')}</h1>`

    - To `<h1>Last Active: {format(getLastActive, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:ss.SSS')}</h1>`

And the same is true for `elapsed`.

- `getElapsedTime` should be be stored in state of its own

  - Remove `const [elapsed, setElapsed] = React.useState(+new Date())`
  - Remove `setElapsed(getElapsedTime())` both places in `useEffect`
  - Change `<h1>Time Elapsed: {elapsed}</h1>`

    - To `<h1>Time Elapsed: {getElapsedTime}</h1>`

**remove `useEffect`**

Now your `useEffect` is empty and it can be removed entirely.

**unnecessary function wrappers**

`useIdleTimer` provides `reset`, `pause`, and `resume`. You do not need to redefine what is already defined. This is similar to the anti-pattern above.

- Remove `const handleReset = () => reset()`
- Change `<button onClick={handleReset}>RESET</button>`

  - To `<button onClick={reset}>RESET</button>`
- Remove `const handlePause = () => pause()`
- Change `<button onClick={handlePause}>PAUSE</button>`

  - To `<button onClick={pause}>PAUSE</button>`
- Remove `const handleResume = () => resume()`
- Change `<button onClick={handleResume}>RESUME</button>`

  - To `<button onClick={resume}>RESUME</button>`

**avoid local state**

`timeout` should be declared as a prop of the `Upload` component

- Remove `const timeout = 3000`
- Change `function Upload() ...`

  - To `function Upload({ timeout = 3000 }) ...`
  - To change timeout, you can pass a prop to the component

    - `<Upload timeout={5000} />`
    - `<Upload timeout={10000} />`

**use the provided example**

Read [Hook Usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-idle-timer) in the react-idle-timer docs. Start there and work your way up.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useIdleTimer } from 'react-idle-timer'
import App from './App'

export default function (props) {
  const handleOnIdle = event => {
    console.log('user is idle', event)
    console.log('last active', getLastActiveTime())
  }

  const handleOnActive = event => {
    console.log('user is active', event)
    console.log('time remaining', getRemainingTime())
  }

  const handleOnAction = event => {
    console.log('user did something', event)
  }

  const { getRemainingTime, getLastActiveTime } = useIdleTimer({
    timeout: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    onIdle: handleOnIdle,
    onActive: handleOnActive,
    onAction: handleOnAction,
    debounce: 500
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {/* your app here */}
    </div>
  )
}
```